# The login failed when connecting to SQL Server. Trusted Domain

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, dynamics-nav, navision

I have a problem with SQL server.
My environment is like this:

trusted domain two active directory.
192.168.0.105 - New Active Directory 
192.168.0.104 - Old Active Directory & Application Server(Navision 2009 R2) with Old Domain
192.168.0.103 - Database Server. SQL Server 2008 with Old Domain

When I try to connect my application (navision 2009 R2) from client computer with new domain, there is an error:

> "The login failed when connecting to SQL Server"

It is happen almost everyday. After around 15 minutes, it can connect again.
I don't know what happend.

How can I check the problem? Is it a problem with the trusted domain or the sql server or navision 2009 R2?

Comment: Have you tried to run Best Practice Analyzer against your NAV server?

Comment: Are Nav server and SQL Server installed on different computers? You should check Event Viewer on the server where Nav service tier is installed (192.168.0.104 I suppose) to see if there are more details on this error. Also try SQL Prifiler to see if this error is thrown by SQL Server?

Comment: I found this warning in Nav Server ->"The Key Distribution Center (KDC) cannot find a suitable certificate to use for smart card logons, or the KDC certificate could not be verified. Smart card logon may not function correctly if this problem is not resolved. To correct this problem, either verify the existing KDC certificate using certutil.exe or enroll for a new KDC certificate."

Comment: and also this one-> "Service: MicrosoftDynamicsNavServer$HO
SQL Query Notifications are unavailable on SQL Server 'NAVDB-SVR' in Database 'PAFL_HO'. The Object Change Listener has switched to polling."

Comment: in Database Server i found this "Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'. Reason: Token-based server access validation failed with an infrastructure error. Check for previous errors. [CLIENT: 192.168.0.104]"

Comment: Not sure what 1st and 3rd errors mean. Eather your Nav server forgeting the type of auth it must use (cuz smart cards is not the one) or your domain controller stops sending proper auth (cuz anonymouse).

Comment: The Object Listener is not the problem it can be set up later. Its the service wich monitors navision objects modification.